# HubSection Background image doesn't show up in the designer - Windows Store

Tags: windows-store-apps

I'm not sure what to do, I set the image correctly and when I run debug on local machine the image shows up in the application, but in the designer it is blank.

```
        <HubSection Width="780" Margin="0,0,80,0">
            <HubSection.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Backgrounds/backGround.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </HubSection.Background>
        </HubSection>
```

Comment: Exact code works for me. Have you tried closing the page in VS, clean/rebuild the solution? Tried another image?

Comment: @ChristiaanV yes that worked, restarting VS did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try either adding a forward slash '/' or 'ms-appx:///' in front of "assets/backgrounds/background.jpg"

```
 <HubSection Width="780" Margin="0,0,80,0">
    <HubSection.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Backgrounds/backGround.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </HubSection.Background>
 </HubSection>



<ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Backgrounds/backGround.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Comment: Aren't a forward slash would point to the root of directories?